# what is the explanation of output of given program

Tags: c

the output of following code is

```
2 1 
3 1 
4 1 
5 1 
6 1
7 0
```

Anyone can please explain?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x=1, y=1;
    for(; y; printf("%d %d\n", x, y))
    {
        y = x++ <= 5;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: What does `printf` return?

Comment: can you guess what is meaning of output :)?

Comment: What part you don't understand?

Comment: why semicolon is given before 'y' in for loop? what is its significance?

Comment: @Priya In C `for..loop` syntax like `for(INITIALIZATION; CONDITION; INCREMENT/DECREMENT)` So here your initialization part is empty.So using `;` C under stand nothing to be initialize. For information regarding to `for..loop` visit http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/c_for

Answer (score 2):

Here is your program reformulated. I think that the behavior is obvious.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
  int x=1, y=1;
  while (y != 0) {
     if (x <= 5) y = 1;
     else y = 0;
     x = x + 1;
     printf("%d %d\n", x, y)) ;
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: why semicolon is given before 'y' in for loop? what is its significance?

Comment: The syntax of for in C is: `for(expr1;expr2;expr3){command}` with meaning `expr1; while(expr2) {command; expr3}`. Any of expr[123] can be empty. In your case expr1 is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Its fairly straightforward - you have

```
for(; y; printf("%d %d\n", x, y))
    {
        y = x++ <= 5;
    }
```

Initially `x=1`, `y=1`.

On first pass: `y = x++ <= 5;` means `y = 1++ <= 5` (so to say) hence by the of this statement - `x=2`, `y=1` - since `1<=5` evaluates to `1`

On second pass: `y = x++ <= 5;` means `y = 2++ <= 5` (so to say) hence by the of this statement - `x=3`, `y=1` - since `1<=5` evaluates to `1`

and it goes on like this until we get `y=0` when `x++ <= 5` evaluates to `6++ <= 6` and then in the `for` loop `for(; y; printf("%d %d\n", x, y))` the condition evaluates to false since y is 0.

Comment: the code first encounters the printf ,and then it encounters the increment and condition checking part.
why it does not print 1 1 the first time

Comment: `why it does not print 1 1 the first time` - because that code is written in the increment/decrement section - `printf` is encountered after loop is entered once not before that/

Answer (score 1):

`y` is used as condition in `for` loop where as you are printing the data in place of incrementation. As `printf` returns `int`, it is totally `valid`.

```
y = x++ <= 5;
```

Means `increment` x and check if `value of x <=5`. if it is then `y = 1`, otherwise `y=0`.
If `y=0`, it will end the loop.

**The program can also be written like.**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x=1, y=1;
    while(y)
    {
        printf("%d %d\n", x, y)
        x++;
        if(x <= 5)
           y=1;
        else
           y=0;
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```